# htlatex crops too much for picture environment

Tags: diagrams, tex4ht, htlatex

I use `htlatex` to convert a large latex file to html pages. All works with one exception. Anything drawn in the `picture` environment gets cropped. I have isolated the problem in the code example below. The three filled circles have parts missing at the top, the bottom, and on the left boundary.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(1.2,1.2)
\put(0.1,0){\circle*{0.2}}
\put(0.1,0){\line(1,2){0.5}}
\put(0.6,1){\circle*{0.2}} 
\put(1.1,0){\circle*{0.2}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

It looks fine when the same source file is converted to a pdf instead.

The line that creates that png file appears to be the following:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=bugreport0x.png -r110x110 -dEPSCrop -dBackgroundColor=16#ffffff -dTextAlphaBits=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=2 -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE zzbugreport.ps -c quit
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `dvipng` instead of default `tex4ht` image conversion, which goes in `dvips` -> `gs` route. It is slow and fragile.The image conversion process can be easily modifed with [make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en). You can configure it with `Make:image` command in a build file:

```
Make:htlatex {}
Make:image("png$",
"dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
```

save it as `filenameofyourtexfile.mk4` and run command:

```
make4ht filenameofyourtexfile
```

First parameter for `Make:image` is a Lua regular expression to match image filename, the second is command template to be executed, with `${variable}` placeholders. All images to be converted are stored in special `dvi` file named `filenameofyourtexfile.idv`. Each page in this file is one image. Variables in the template are: `output` is file name of the generated image, `page` is page number of the image and source is filename of the `.idv` file.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I don't seem to be able to figure out how to install `make4ht` on my Mac. I have tex4ht, pandoc, and of course texlive through macports, but none of these come with make4ht.

Comment: @Norbert it is part of official TeX Live distribution, you can try to [install it yourself](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Comment: Thank you for this!

`htlatex` first uses `dvips` to create a postscript file from an `idv` file--this is where the trimming happens--and then `gs` to create the `png` file.  Using `dvipng` to get from idv to png directly, appears to solve the problem.

I think I'll write some shell script that that does things like
     `dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight shell.idv -pp 3 -o shell1x.png`

Comment: @Norbert you can find image file names and pages in the `.lg` file. but in this case I wouldn't use `htlatex` anyway, because it would compile the images twice

Comment: Thanks!  Even better. I have it working now, using `dvipng`.